# SAS Encoding html file utf-8

Tags: html, encoding, utf-8, sas

Basically,I have a SAS script which sends email to different users.
I want to attach some html file with encoding to `utf-8` but it doesn't work: "`Invalid string`".

This is the example script:

```
filename outmail email encoding='wcyrillic'
subject="Test"
from='test.test@test.kz';

data _NULL_ ; 
file outmail 
to = ('test2.test@test.kz')    
attach=("/user_data/Kontury_Vse_Filialy.html" ENCODING='utf-8');    
put"Hello!"; 
run;
```

It works properly on attaching other files such `csv.` or attaching html with encoding `'wcyrillic'`.It seems to me that SAS has troubles with encoding html files from `CP1251` to `utf-8`, but it looks weird.

Comment: Are you sure that your file "/user_data/Kontury_Vse_Filialy.html" is saved with 'utf-8' encoding?

Comment: @Bagin, no, I just want to send this file with UTF-8 encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ENCODING option defines what encoding SAS have to use to read attached file.

If you want to write attachment with utf-8 encoding to email stream use OUTENCODING option instead.

```
attach=("/user_data/Kontury_Vse_Filialy.html" OUTENCODING='utf-8');
```

More details about attach options you can find [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/63323/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0ig2krarrz6vtn1aw9zzvtez4qo.htm).

Comment: I added OUTENCODING  to my script but, finally,after sending this html doesn't change encoding =(